# Retrieve free data

Tags: sql-server-2008

Goal:
Review data

Problem:
Where can I get a database with free data for SQL server?     I need to review data to improve my ability as data analyst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsft set up a CodePlex site for sample SQL Server implementation -- http://sqlserversamples.codeplex.com -- the AdventureWorks sample database for 2005, 2008, and 2012 are linked right at the top of the page.

For some reason the Contoso BI samples aren't hosted there (or at least I can't find them), and can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18279).

Answer (score 2):

The Adventureworks sample database: http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55926